# Block folder in nginx and ALL contents inside, throw 404 EXCEPT for localhost. Browser is requesting script download

Tags: nginx

Here is my code:

```
# I had to do this one because going .com/restricted was throwing 403, not 404.
location /restricted {
    return 404;
}

#This seemed to work except I don't want localhost to have 404, I want it to access correctly
location ~ /restricted/(.+)\.php$ {
     deny all;
     return 404;
     allow 127.0.0.1;
}
```

So, basically:

1. Get 404 everytime NON-localhost tries to access restricted OR its contents (e.g. `/restricted/should_be_restricted_script.php`)
2. Whenever I try to access the folder, the browser asks me if I want to download the script... When I saved and opened it, it was `should_be_restricted_script.php` indeed, and I can't figure out why...

Can someone help me? tyvm

Comment: Do you want to run php too? If your `nginx.conf` is correct the server will run php not serve.

Comment: @uzsolt it runs PHP in all other scripts, just serves those inside restricted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
location ~ /restricted/(.+)\.php$ {
  deny all;
  return 404;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
}   
location ~ ^/restricted {
  return 404;
}
```

I think that your problem is related about how nginx chooses the "best" location, he gives priority to non regexp location.

Look at this [article](http://fisharebest.stonystratford.org/116/understanding-nginx-location-rules/)

Comment: I'll try this when home, what is 498?

Comment: sorry my mistake, I was returning 498 in order to return a diferent code on my test env.

Comment: it might have worked but I am still in doubt. I wrote `deny all` and `return 404` without allow, but still was able to run `php test.php` from the console while in ssh to the server. Shouldn't I be able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `deny` and `allow` rows, because the first match will apply:

```
location ~ /restricted/(.+)\.php$ {
   allow 127.0.0.1;
   deny all;
}
```